# Additional form content depending on button pressed

Tags: jquery, forms

Is it possible to do something similar to:

```
$(".T1C1butn").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "/article/" + $(".T1C1Fetch").innerHTML);        
});
```

but instead of modifying the action of the form depending on which button was pressed, modify the data sent i.e. if the user presses the button `'Testbtn'` then `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="url">` with value 'www.example.com' is submitted in the post request and if they press a different button then the value for url is different.

Comment: you mean depending on the button, the url of the input element should change?

Comment: I mean that if I were to use a standard form, it could contain say 3 fields (name, DOB, email), I would like to have a number of buttons, which when you press say 'ButtonOne' it submit the POST and sends off 'John", "8th October", "email@example.com" but if you press 'ButtonTwo' it submits the POST and sends "Bob", "1st January", "test@email.com" etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate inputs with specific values based on which button is clicked, you would bind an event handler to each button click and assign the input values using jQuery's `.val()`.

I would also recommend separating the functionality of populating and submitting the form so that the user can be sure the correct values are populated before submitting.  In the example below, hitting buttons Data 1/2/3 populates the fields, and hitting button 'Submit' submits the form.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/oatyz6md/

HTML:

```
<form action="your url" method="post">
    <button id="T1C1butn1">Data 1</button>
    <button id="T1C1butn2">Data 2</button>
    <button id="T1C1butn3">Data 3</button><br />
    <input id="name" name="name" /><br />
    <input id="dob" name="dob" /><br />
    <input id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {

    $("#T1C1butn1").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#name').val('John');
        $('#dob').val('8 October');
        $('#email').val('john@example.com');
    });

    $("#T1C1butn2").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#name').val('Steve');
        $('#dob').val('12 September');
        $('#email').val('steve@example.com');
    });

    $("#T1C1butn3").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#name').val('Mike');
        $('#dob').val('1 January');
        $('#email').val('mike@example.com');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would need to do this. That said, the easiest way would probably be to store the values in a custom data attribute on the buttons themselves then when clicked, get the stored values and load them into the elements:

```js
$(function () {
     
    $(".btn").click(function () {
      // get info from button
      var info = $(this).data('info').split(',');
      // set info to the inputs
      $.each(info, function(i,e){
        $('#myForm input').eq(i).val(e);
      });
      // submit form
      // $('#myForm').submit(); // commented out because submit doesnt work in SO snippets
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mypage.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="name"/><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" value="dob" /><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="email" /><br />
</form>

<button class="btn" data-info="John,8 October,john@example.com">Data 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-info="Steve,12 September,steve@example.com">Data 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-info="Mike,1 January,mike@example.com">Data 3</button><br />
```